# Using php to loop through mysql table, why aren't elseif statements working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, while-loop

I have a set of pages that take two boundaries (from user input) which result in one value that then gets placed in a mysql table. This value is then used as a boundary, the process repeats itself, a new value gets created and added to the sql table.

Now, there is a precise order to this process, and i have tried to use if/else if statements to order them:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partitions 
WHERE subject_id = $subject_id AND stimulus = $stimulus", $DB);

if(!result) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());}

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if($row[6] == NULL){

    $query1  = "UPDATE partitions SET t_1_2 = $t_half WHERE subject_id = $subject_id AND stimulus = $stimulus";
    mysql_query($query1) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query1);

    $target_page = "pan00";
    $next_t_a = $row[2];   // from user input
    $next_t_b = $t_half;   // can i replace $t_half by $row[6]?

}


elseif($row[4] == NULL)
    {

    $query1  = "UPDATE partitions SET t_1_4 = $t_half WHERE subject_id = $subject_id AND stimulus = $stimulus";
    mysql_query($query1) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query1);

    $target_page = "pan00";
    $next_t_a = $row[2];
    $next_t_b = $row[4]; }


elseif($row[3] == NULL)
    {

    $query1  = "UPDATE partitions SET t_1_8 = $t_half WHERE subject_id = $subject_id AND stimulus = $stimulus";
    mysql_query($query1) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query1);

    $target_page = "CE";
    $next_t_a = $row[4];
    $next_t_b = $row[6]; }
```

I thought using else if statements would check for a condition being true, and if it was would just execute the code in brackets and skip the loop but here both $row[6] and $row[4] get updated at the same time. Does this have something to do with the while loop i set up to fetch the row values?

I tried using goto and break but to no avail.

The problem is in the while loop (thanks to those who pointed it out), which brings me to my next question: how can I use the mysql data without this while loop? Removing it makes the page crash as if php didn't store the results?

Comment: For each `while` iteration only one of the conditions will be executed. Which means, on the first one, the first condition could be met, but on the second - some other condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` statement will stop when no rows are available anymore. If you express an assignment in a `while` loop in `PHP`, the condition will be considered true as long as the variable is effective (not `NULL`). Otherwise the loop will end.